# SQL Update Concat Array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, concatenation

I'm trying to add values to existing array of integers column. I'm using this query.

```
UPDATE users SET conversations_id = CONCAT(conversations_id, '{2,3}');
```

and it's giving me this error.

```
ERROR:  column "conversations_id" is of type integer[] but expression is of 
type text
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET conversations_id = CONCAT(conversations_id,...
                                        ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 37
```

I understand that it's telling me that second argument is text, but it demands it to be written that way, like in here.

```
UPDATE users SET conversations_id = '{1,2,3}';
```

I have tried casting second argument to an array but I'm not sure how. I also tried mark it as VARIADIC but again, I don't know how to do it in this case.

How do I add new values to this array?

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) the operator to append an array to another array is either `||` or the function `array_cat()`. `concat()` is **only** for text/varchar values.

So you need to use:

```
UPDATE users 
   SET conversations_id = conversations_id || '{2,3}'::int[];
```

or

```
UPDATE users 
   SET conversations_id = array_cat(conversations_id, '{2,3}'::int[]);
```